# C# regex filtering

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get value of XML:

```
<usr_clan_id>123</usr_clan_id>
```

I need get 123, its example.
I'll tried to use:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"<usr_clan_id>([0-9])</usr_clan_id>$",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But it's bad :/

Comment: Use an xml parser to parse xml not Regex.

Comment: Try XPath it's a much better approach than RegEx.

Comment: Yep. Agree with @L.B. There are plenty of XML tools out there. Don't pick the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Or, to put it another way - anytime you're thinking of XML as a string, you're doing something wrong. Yes, you'll usually find it (in a readable from) as a string, but that's not how you should be dealing with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var value = doc.XPathSelectElement("//usr_clan_id").Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<usr_clan_id>123</usr_clan_id>");
int id = (int)xdoc.Element("usr_clan_id");
```

Comment: I suggest [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7.aspx) because there is no way to be sure that there will be just digits in the value.

Comment: @slosd yes, *if* it is possible to have non-integer value in this tag, then `Int32.TryParse((string)xdoc.Element("usr_clan_id"), out value)` will do the job without exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a huge XML file, use a parser and get the value with XPath as suggested in the comments. If you only get the short XML string you included in your question, RegEx is perfectly fine in my opinion.

About the regular expression: You only match one digit. Instead use `+` which matches one or more digits.

```
@"<usr_clan_id>([0-9]+)</usr_clan_id>$"
```

Comment: Where would you pick as a sensible cut-off point? If people treat "short" pieces of XML as strings, when should they stop doing so?

Comment: As soon as attributes, namespaces or more than one element are involved regex is no good. It would be interesting though if the parser has any overhead compared to a regex match.

Comment: So, at a point where the lead in portion is an exact, known string. So you can accomplish the transform with cheaper string comparisons and substring operations, rather than regex?

Comment: Yes. You are of course totally right that regex is not the cheapest approach here, but asuming that Razor isn't all that interested in high performance I would favor readability over performance.
As long as this code isn't executed n hundredthousand times it doesn't even matter if you care about performance.